# Searching Shared Envelopes in Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently using the docusign api to make a request that searches the user's folders in order to bring back all the envelopes that are out for signature. This works but it doesn't seem to bring back envelopes from shared folders.

Having executed the 'list' api action I can see that my user has access to another user's folders and having logged in as that user I can see that some signing requests have been sent. I'm just wondering if this is a limitation of the API search function or whether I'll have to perform a list then iterate through each folder requesting envelopes, the search API function has been quite useful as it allows me to return recipient information as a part of the request whereas it seems that listitems doesn't allow that.

Edit: I'm looking to perform a lookup that will bring back all of the envelopes that have been sent by user A and user B that are out for signature.

The situation is that we have multiple company accounts that can send docusign documents to customers. What we need to be able to do is to view all documents that are out for signature across all accounts in one single list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify (by editing your question) what results you want: all of User A's outstanding envelopes? Or User A and B's envelopes? Or the envelopes that User A did not send but are awaiting his or her signature? Or the envelopes User A either signed or was cc'd on but were sent by someone else and the envelopes are not signed yet?

Comment: Edited, I'm looking for all envelopes that are out for signature on both accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/list/ 
call GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders this will return list of folders which userA has access to, this will also include the list of userB folders. Once you get folderId from previous call then use below call to get the list of envelopes in the folder

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/folders/{folderId}
```

Comment: This is the approach I used in the end but it's not really ideal as I had to perform additional requests to get each envelope's full data. It would be better if it were possible to perform the search request and include shared envelopes however it seems this won't be possible so I'll mark this as correct